# RabbitMQ creating multiple connections

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqplib

Here is the producer code:

```js
import * as amqp from "amqplib";

export default class Producer {
    channel;

    async createChannel() {
        const connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost");
        this.channel = await connection.createChannel();
    }

    async publishMessage(routingKey, message) {
        if (!this.channel) {
            console.log("called");
            await this.createChannel();
        }

        const exchangeName = "loggerEx";
        await this.channel.assertExchange(exchangeName, "direct");

        const logDetails = {
            logType: routingKey,
            message: message,
            dateTime: new Date(),
        };
        await this.channel.publish(
            exchangeName,
            routingKey,
            Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(logDetails))
        );

        console.log(`The new ${routingKey} log is sent to exchange ${exchangeName}`);
    }
}
```

Here is how I am using `Producer` class:

**server.js**

```js
import Producer from "./producer.js";

const producer = new Producer();

producer.publishMessage("info", "somemessage");
producer.publishMessage("info", "somemessage");
```

In RabbitMQ management UI, I see two connections:

[image]

In `Producer` class I am checking for the existence of the channel.

```js
        if (!this.channel) {
            console.log("called");
            await this.createChannel();
        }
```

then why connection is being created multiple times.

Here is the output when I run the file:

```bash
$ node server.js 
called
called
The new info log is sent to exchange loggerEx
The new info log is sent to exchange loggerEx
```

Comment: How many time that the `console.log("called");` is logged?

Comment: @YuvarajM twice

Comment: Thats why two conn are created, try to log `this.channel` to check why it is in false or use another variable like `isConnCreated = false` and set to true after conn created

Comment: tried, still same

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was due to the missing `await` keyword:

```js
await producer.publishMessage("info", "somemessage");
await producer.publishMessage("info", "somemessage");
```